# Failed to query a users APPDATA folder if the user name contains german umlauts

Tags: c, windows, shell, mingw, codepages

I'm trying check if a folder exists inside the users APPDATA folder. The following program works when called from a **cmd** or **cygwin** shell but fails from inside a **mingw** shell if the envrionment variable **APPDATA** has the value **C:\User\Lieschen Müller**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
  const char *   appdata;
  DWORD          result;

  if (NULL != (appdata = getenv ("APPDATA"))) {
     result = GetFileAttributes (appdata);

     if (INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES == result) {
        fprintf (stderr, "<%s> = INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES\n", appdata);
         result = 1;
      }
      else if (!(FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY & result)) {
         fprintf (stderr, "<%s> = ! FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY\n", appdata);
         result = 1;
      }
      else {
         fprintf (stderr, "<%s> OK\n", appdata);
         result = 0;
      }
   }
   else {
      fprintf (stderr, "Failed to lookup APPDATA environment variable\n");  
      result = 1;
   }

   return (int) result;
}
```

Inside **cmd** or **cygwin** the character at the position of the **ü** is **0xFC** but inside **mingw** it is **0x81** (0xFFFFFF81).

I have also tried to use the following piece of code with no success.

```
SHGetSpecialFolderPath (NULL, appdata, CSIDL_APPDATA, FALSE)
```

The call returns **FALSE** and **GetLastError()** return error code **3** (**ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND**).

Is there something I'm missing to setup when running the given program from inside a **mingw** shell?

Comment: You probably need to use multi-byte charactes.

Comment: Hello Paul, even if I use **_wgetenv()** and **GetFileAttributesW()** it doesn't work when running from inside a **mingw** shell.

Comment: I also have a response 3 (`ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`) to `SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, myVar)` when the Windows username is all-cyrillic. This does not happen with `SHGetFolderPathA(...)`. Running all of the above from mingw32 shell.